# How can I get a string date in the format "2016-07-06T10:57Z" from Date() and toISOString

Tags: javascript

I need to get a date in this format:

```
2016-07-06T10:57Z
```

Using this code I have been able to get a date in a format somewhat like I need:

```
var isoDate = new Date().toISOString();

2016-07-06T08:46:08.127Z
```

But is there a way I can remove the seconds and fraction of seconds from the date so it appears exactly like the date: "2016-07-06T10:57Z" ?

Comment: use momentjs library. It does pretty much anything you need with Date and Time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always want to remove the last 8 characters ('Z' included) thus you can use a function like `slice`

```
isoDate = isoDate.slice(0, -8); //Remove seconds + fractions + Z
isoDate += "Z"; //Add back the Z
```

You can use this way because the format returned by `toISOString()` will always be

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
var isoDate = new Date().toISOString();
var pos = isoDate.lastIndexOf(':');
var datePart1 = isoDate.substring(0,pos);
var datePart2 = isoDate.substr(-1, 1);
var dateStr = datePart1+datePart2;
console.log(dateStr);
```